# Need code of edited things through admin panel

Tags: magento2, code

How we can get the **code** of edited pages through the admin panel?

Comment: I want to find the code if even I made change in admin panel. E.g If i tried to make changes in content of home page in html editor through admin panel. Then how we can track that exact code written in html editor in files of magento.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to track which admin user made changes in the CMS page (and at which date and time).

For this, you can create a module and observe the event **cms_page_prepare_save** or **model_save_before** (or maybe **model_save_after**) to get the information whether the data has changed or not.

In the observer class, you can use:

```
$object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
```

to get the object of event, and then use:

```
$object->getOrigData();
```

to get the data before saving.

and

```
$object->getData();
```

which is going to be saved.

I hope the above information is sufficient to start.